# Is there any way to hide the little diagonal lines at the bottom right of a resizable div?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to make my table columns resizable. So I put a `div` inside the `th` and made those `divs` resizable. Problem is, there is an ugly pair of diagonal lines inside each of those resizable `divs`. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: I've posted an answer below, if it doesn't solve your problem, please post an code snippet or an example

Comment: Please post an example reproducing the problem. Without it is hard to help

Comment: If you don't like the _"ugly diagonal lines"_, make sure to replace with some other visual indicator for your users. **No** _"ugly diagonal lines"_ is worse than having _"ugly diagonal lines"_ from a UX angle. There should be an visual indicator that says, _"I'm resizable!"_

Comment: Leave them there.

Answer (score 0):

This element is rendered by the browser itself and is not part of the HTML spec. There is one work around and that is to position another element over the top of the corner to hide it.

The text area will still be resizable keep in mind.

```css
textarea {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.corner {
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: -5px;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="corner"></div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code on my table but the behavior is a bit weird
https://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/v7k41887/

The div only expands a certain bit before going haywire